# PostgreSQL 10.4 - how to index jsonb for sql functions not operators?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a table named "k3_order" with jsonb column "json_delivery".

Example content of that column is:

```json
{
    "delivery_cost": "11.99",
    "packageNumbers": [
        "0000000596034Q"
    ]
}
```

I've created index on json_delivery->'packageNumbers':

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx ON k3_order USING gin(json_delivery->'packageNumbers');
```

Now I use this two SQL Queries:

```
SELECT id, delivery_method_id 
FROM k3_order 
WHERE jsonb_exists (json_delivery->'packageNumbers', '0000000596034Q');

SELECT id, delivery_method_id 
FROM k3_order 
WHERE json_delivery->'packageNumbers' ? '0000000596034Q';
```

The second is faster and using index, but the first doesn't.

Is there any way to create index in PostgreSQL 10.4 in order for query 1) to use it?

Is this even possible in PostgreSQL 10.4 or newer versions?

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT id, delivery_method_id 
FROM k3_order 
WHERE jsonb_exists (json_delivery->'packageNumbers', > '0000000596034Q');
```

produces:

```
Seq Scan on k3_order  (cost=0.00..117058.10 rows=216847 width=8 (actual time=162.001..569.863 rows=1 loops=1)
Filter: jsonb_exists((json_delivery -> 'packageNumbers'::text), '0000000596034Q'::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 650539

Planning time: 0.748 ms
Execution time: 569.886 ms
```

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT id, delivery_method_id 
FROM k3_order 
WHERE json_delivery->'packageNumbers' ? '0000000596034Q';
```

produces:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on k3_order  (cost=21.04..2479.03 rows=651 width=8) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
Recheck Cond: ((json_delivery -> 'packageNumbers'::text) ? '0000000596034Q'::text)
Heap Blocks: exact=1
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_idx  (cost=0.00..20.88 rows=651 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((json_delivery -> 'packageNumbers'::text) ? '0000000596034Q'::text)

Planning time: 0.182 ms
Execution time: 0.050 ms
```

Comment: I just checked, and `jsonb_exists` has no support function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes can only be used by queries in the following cases:

- the `WHERE` condition contains an expression of the form `<indexed expression> <operator> <constant>`, where

  - an index has been created on `<indexed expression>`
  - `<operator>` is an operator in the index family of the operator class of the index
  - `<constant>` is an expression that stays constant for the duration of the index scan
- the `ORDER BY` clause has the same or the exact opposite ordering as the index definition, and the index access method supports sorting (from v13 on, an index can also be used if it contains the starting columns of the `ORDER BY` clause)
- the PostgreSQL version is v12 and higher, and the `WHERE` condition contains an expression of the form `bool_func(...)`, where the function returns `boolean` and has a [planner support function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-optimization.html).

Now `json_delivery->'packageNumbers' ? '0000000596034Q'` satisfies the first condition, so an index scan can be used.

`jsonb_exists(json_delivery->'packageNumbers', > '0000000596034Q')` could only use an index if there were a planner support function for `jsonb_exists`, but there is none:

```
SELECT prosupport FROM pg_proc
WHERE proname = 'jsonb_exists';

 prosupport 
════════════
 -
(1 row)
```

Comment: Well jsonb_exists returns boolean, it should work that way. Here is a list of all PostgreSQL json related functions: https://github.com/tztztztz/List-of-all-PostgreSQL-10-operators/blob/master/full-list.txt

Comment: Yes, but see my final query, which shows that it has no support function. So it won't work. We would probably welcome a patch to add a support function.

Comment: It would be ideal for ORM I'm using if that kind of query would use the index: 

```SELECT id, delivery_method_id FROM k3_order WHERE jsonb_exists(CAST(jsonb_object_field_text(json_delivery, 'packageNumbers')  as jsonb), '0000000596034Q')```

Comment: As I said, you are welcome to write a patch.

Comment: Well, I've just installed PostgreSQL 13 on another test machine, and
```sql
SELECT prosupport FROM pg_proc
WHERE proname = 'jsonb_exists';
```

shows it is supported, but the other query still doesn't use the index.

Comment: I ran that query on v13, and standard PostgreSQL has no support function. What are you using, and what exactly is the result you get?

Comment: Version: PostgreSQL 13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit



```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'jsonb_exists';
```


It produces:



> "4047" "jsonb_exists" "11" "10" "12" 1 0 0 "-" "f" false false true false "i" "s" 2 0 "16" "3802 25" "jsonb_exists"

Comment: Yes, but what is in the `prosupport` column?

Comment: Well it's empty, but still better than no result, so I'm assuming at some point it may be supported. Until that I will make it around ORM using native postgresql driver, but still it's not an ideal solution for me.